# Looking for advice on color calibration through ubuntu color settings for my LG C1 OLED

Tags: display, color-management

I've recently decided to daily drive Ubuntu instead of Windows 10, and I was looking into how to get HDR working on my LG OLED(OLED55C1PUB), but from what I can tell HDR is not supported on Ubuntu based on some research I did, but please correct me if I am wrong. One alternative I've seen is adjusting the color profile in the Ubuntu settings and I was wondering if anyone had any knowledge on what would be best for my specific display? Thank you in advance for any help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Are you using the vanilla Gnome Ubuntu flavor? If not, then what? And which version?